# Facebook Customer Chat Plugin not showing when using mobile data

Tags: javascript, wordpress, facebook, facebook-messenger

I've been using Wordpress [Facebook Customer Chat Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook-messenger-customer-chat/) and it was working perfectly until we tried checking using mobile data and it didn't show, we tried it on different devices using both WiFi and mobile data and it only shows when using WiFi is there a way to avoid this issue?

this is my current code:

```
<div id='fb-root'></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&autoLogAppEvents=1';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
  <div class='fb-customerchat'
    attribution="wordpress"
    page_id='#########'
    theme_color='#ed1c24'
  >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no relation between using wifi or mobile data so your issue is most likely related to requests being blocked on mobile (firewall/proxy, ad blocker apps or similar) or the mobile browser you try to test this with. Customer Chat Plugin only works on latest mobile browsers and does not work on Facebook's in-app-browser.